# Google Play Leaderboards Not Showing Up

Tags: android, actionscript-3, leaderboard, google-play-games

So I'm trying to implement Google Games Leaderboards into an AS3 game. As near as I can tell, game services is all set up appropriately. Achievements and in-app purchases are already functioning properly. I have all my leaderboard set up in the developer console and I don't see anything obvious wrong with them. I know the leaderboard IDs have been properly implemented into my code. According to the console, I've even managed to successfully submit some scores to said leaderboards.

However my problem is the leaderboards are not displaying in-app. The leaderboard interface comes up, but simply says "No leaderboards for this game". I can't for the life of me figure out why. The only thing I can think of is maybe they just aren't available yet, though I made them over 24 hours ago at this point. There are 96 of them, which is obviously quite a few (though, documentation says I can have as many as 100).

So do I just have to wait? Did I make a booboo somewhere? Is there a giant red button I forgot to click in the dev console somewhere? Can you even test leaderboards before publishing the game? I'm so confused...

Answer (score 2):

If achievements are working but leaderboards are not, here's my guess: did you add leaderboards to the developer console *after* publishing and forgot to publish the changes? After publishing, every time you change something, you have to hit "Publish Changes" to make those changes effective.

1. Open play.google.com/apps/publish
2. Click the game settings tab (joystick icon)
3. Click on your game
4. Go to the "Publishing" tab (on the left)
5. It *should* say "There are no changes to be published. Everything is published." If it says otherwise, you may need to click on the "Publish Changes" button!

Comment: I have yet to actually publish the game services. In fact it won't even allow me to yet, as I haven't uploaded achievement images.

Comment: I recognize your name! You write the iOS Plugin! :D