# Play Games Personal Leaderboad score not showing up

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

My achievements are showing up in Play Games, but my personal leaderboard score does not show up. It is enabled and published in the play games developer console.

It is also integrated in my Android Java code. I would like to view and share my personal highscore.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: If you change something in your app you need to hit "Publish Changes" button. You should this message "There are no changes to be published. Everything is published.", if not you need to click "Publish Changes" button. See [SO-19527199](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527199/google-play-leaderboards-not-showing-up). Also, you may also want to look at this [forum](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/44844-google-play-games-services-cannot-show-leaderboard/) which suggests checking the keystore you have used and also  to unpublish and remove OAuth then publish it again.

Comment: @gerardnimo I tried it all, but no luck so far.